# Run python file in module mode using VS Code debugger

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Here's my directory structure -

```
src
    Main.py
    Message.py
    ...
    __init__.py
```

In `Main.py`, I have an import statement `import src.Message`. This works fine when I execute the file on my own using the command `python3 -m src.Main.py`

However, when I use the VS code debugger to do the same, I get a `ModuleNotFoundException`.

I assumed that this was because the debugger doesn't use the `-m` flag, so I used the run Module configuration in the VS Code debugger.

I entered `src.Main.py` in that, and while the program does start, the debugger is unable to connect to it, and I get an error a few seconds later.

[image: error message]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was the `parent folder of 'src'` has not been added to the `sys.path`.

You run `python3 -m src.Main.py` under the location of `src's` parent folder, is that right? Then the location of `src`'s parent folder will be added to the `sys.path`.

So, you need to configure the launch.json file in order to add the related path to the `sys.path`.

If you open the folder of `src` in the VSCode:

```
  "env": {
    "PYTHONPATH": "../"
  },
```

If you open the folder of `src's parent` in the VSCode:

```
  "env": {
    "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}"
  },
```

The launch.json will be looks like this:

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: Current File",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "env": {
            "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}"
          },
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to debug a Module in VSCode, you don't include the `.py` file extension (only `src.Main`). In your case, your `launch.json` file should look like this:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Module",  // Whatever name you see fit!
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "src.Main"
        }
    ]
}
```

An alternative configuration based on the directory instead of the module name:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python Program",  // Whatever name you see fit!
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/src/Main.py",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

For more information on Python debugging configuration, you can check [this link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging)

Comment: @dumbPotato21 If you have multiple module you want to debug you can use extension [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable) and the command `extension.commandvariable.file.relativeDirDots` to get a dot separated path to the file